# Как изменить цвет текста в самом верху экрана девайса

Tags: java, android, activity, android-themes

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить цвет текста в самом верху экрана?
Вопрос на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это сложная задача которую в любом случае не реализовать на всех версиях, а на некоторых можно, но затемнение всё одно не убрать. Минимум что нужно знать - это атрибут в стилях `colorPrimaryDark`, а полоска называется `statusBar`

Comment: <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы задать цвет статус бару и навигационной панели, для версии >= 21 нужно декларивать в themes.xml нечто вроде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="AppTheme.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColorLight</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

ключевые поля: `android:statusBarColor`, `android:navigationBarColor` и `android:colorPrimaryDark`

Дальше, настоятельно рекомендуется в манифесте в теге `<application>`, задекларировать:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.max_aspect"
        android:value="2.1" />
```

Без этого - в новых "широкоугольных" аппаратах работать не будет.

P.S. Пояснения по цветам такие:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]